# how to generate synthetic data for 2 tables with one-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, r, excel, random-data

how to generate synthetic data for 2 tables with one-to-many relationship?
I have the following problem, I have 2 tables of a bank and I was asked to make up the data.

Table 1 corresponds to the table where the credit card sales information is:
`Sales_id`, `Product_ID`, `Sales_Date`

Table 2 has to contain the data of the transactions that the customers make to pay the bank once they get their card:
`Quota_ID`, `Sales_ID`, `Quota_Value`, `Quota_Date`

The problem is that the values generated in table 2 must depend on the date the card was sold, since the transactions of the quotas must be after the bank gave the card to the customer, does anyone have an idea of how I can generate this data in a synthetic way?

Table 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s15m.png)

Table 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWYmK.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just added some pictures to the question and what I need to do in table 2. The problem is that it is too much data to do it manually.

Comment: Can you put the data directly into your question? It will save us time. It is better to have the data directly.